# adding date column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a column of order_date in a table named dates:

```
order_date
"2011-02-01"
"2012-03-23"
"2011-01-01"
"2011-07-04"
```

I'm trying to extract the dates and add it to a new column. I used the formula

```
select EXTRACT(day from order_date) 
from dates
```

to get the dates from the column.

Now to add the values in another column in I tried the following:

```
update dates 
   set date1 = select EXTRACT(day from order_date) from dates;
```

But unfortunately the above code is not working and gives me an error at the 'select' part.

Comment: I have to write a CASE statement for the all the dates below 10. The entries before or on the 10th of each month have to be treated differently from the other dates.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `select`

```
update dates 
   set date1 = EXTRACT(day from order_date);
```

But this seems rather useless. As a general rule you should not store information that can be derived from existing data. The overhead of extracting the day from a date is so small that storing that in another column really does not make sense.

Online example: http://rextester.com/NPONE96895

Comment: I have to write a CASE statement for the all the dates below 10. The entries before or on the 10th of each month have to be treated differently from the other dates

Comment: @OmerQureshi: there is nothing in your original question that indicates that. Please don't add additional requirements to your question once you get an answer.

Comment: I'm not asking for additional help. Someone asked me as to why I need a column and I replied I have to use a CASE statement. The purpose of this question is to get a new column with dates. Unfortunately, the code you have mentioned above does not work

Comment: @OmerQureshi: the query works according to the information you provided in your question: http://rextester.com/NPONE96895

Comment: Yes it works. I realized the problem here. I create a table with only one value. Thanks

Comment: @OmerQureshi But storing this information still sounds like a bad idea. A view that calculates this will be more efficient.